# Error in integrating Parse and Facebook into Android app

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, parse-platform

I am trying to integrate Parse and Facebook into my app. When I want to make the Facebook login I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.Facebook
```

The code I use to initialize my Parse and ParseFacebookUtils:

```
public class App extends Application {
    public static Bitmap profilePicture;

    private static String PARSE_APPLICATION_ID;
    private static String PARSE_CLIENT_KEY;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        PARSE_APPLICATION_ID = getResources().getString(R.string.PARSE_APPLICATION_ID);
        PARSE_CLIENT_KEY = getResources().getString(R.string.PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);

        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);

        ParseFacebookUtils.initialize();

    }
}
```

I included Parse-1.9.0.jar and ParseFacebookUtilsV3-1.9.0.jar in my app. If someone could help me that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the Facebook SDK wasn't loaded. I fixed it by using

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1'
```

instead of

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
```

I think (since Parse is using FacebookUtils**V3**) Parse requires Facebook SDK V3 instead of V4.

Answer (score 0):

Bart, You can use Facebook v4 also. For that use ParseFacebookUtils4 instead ParseFacebookUtils3.

Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366107/parse-and-facebook-integration-no-class-def-found-error/29375868#29375868) for clear example.